# how to get around react infinite loop inside map inside useMemo()

Tags: reactjs

I have looked into the answers for this problem but I am not understanding how it applies to what I am doing, would appreciate some guidance on how to get around this react loop from me setting the state...

```
  const [budgetYear, setBudgetYear] = useState(0);
  const [budgetMonth, setBudgetMonth] = useState(0);
  const [budgetCustomer, setBudgetCustomers] = useState([] as String[]);

  const test=[{
    "myId": "",
    "myLabel": ""
  }] 

  useMemo(() =>{

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(test)) {
      data.push(
        [ 
          'value1',                                                       
          'value2',                 
          'value3'
        ],      

      )

      dateCols.map((date: any, index: any) => { 
        let year = Number(dateCols[index]['name'].split("-")[0])
        let month = Number(dateCols[index]['name'].split("-")[1])

        const writeBudgetItems = () => {
          console.log('writing stuff')
          setBudgetYear(year)
          setBudgetMonth(month-1)
          setBudgetCustomers(['123','234','345','456'])
        }
        writeBudgetItems()
      })
}},[test, dateCols])
```

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` is only for when you want to return a value from the callback, you should be using the `useEffect` hook for this example. In addition, you shouldn't have the `test` variable inside the dependency array (`[test, dateCols]`) since that is causing the infinite re-renders since you're declaring it inside the function component as a normal variable (which means that its value changes each render, causing the useMemo callback to be invoked each time). You should use `useState` to create the `test` variable (and the `dateCols` variable) so they don't trigger the callback in each render:

```
const [test, setTest] = useState([{
    "myId": "",
    "myLabel": ""
  }])
```